# On Linux (Mint) MATE How Can I Make ALT+TAB Switch Between Only The Current Workspace's Windows

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, workspaces, alt-tab

For some reason my version of Linux Mint MATE is configured to switch between applications on *any* workspace when I use `ALT+TAB`.

Simple question: is there any way to limit it to only switch between applications on my *current* workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another answer on Ask Ubuntu which addressed this by having you switch four system settings (swapping the values of two for the other two).  However, it didn't work for me ... but it did lead me to finding a similar approach that *did* work.

First, I installed and ran `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`, followed by `dconf-editor`). This was just to get a GUI app for system editing, but you could also just use the (already installed) command-line `gsettings` instead if you want.

Then I changed two settings (swapping one for the other):

```
org.mate.marco.global-keybindings.cycle-windows
org.mate.marco.global-keybindings.switch-windows-all
```

I also could have swapped `switch-windows-all` for `switch-windows` instead of `cycle-windows`, but `switch-windows` does that preview thing, making it a lot slower on my computer (if you like the preview, use `switch-windows` instead).